# How to combine multiple .txt files into a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing, txt

I am trying to import 250 .txt files that are in one directory as one grouped data frame so that the dataframe consists of two columns with one column taking on the .txt file name and one column containing the actual text.

let's say I have 250 speech data files named a.txt b.txt c.txt etc:

the code I've been trying to use is:

```
os.chdir(r'/Users/alldata')
all_files = glob.glob(r'/Users/alldata/*.txt')
print(all_files)

list = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_fwf(filename, delimiter="\n", header=None,encoding='cp1252')[0].str.cat()
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

In the end my dataframe should look like this:

| filename | text |
| --- | --- |
| a | trump stated that... |
| b | biden refers to.... |

I've tried several options. However I'm getting a long error message with this at the end. I assume that my files are encoded differently and hence cannot use encoding='cp1252'.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 784: character maps to

When only importing one text file, the code works

```
text= pd.read_fwf(r'/Users/alldata/a.txt', delimiter="\n", header=None,encoding='cp1252')[0].str.cat()
df = pd.DataFrame([text], columns=['text'])
# Concatenate all DataFrames
big_df   = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

How to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the encoding parameter or use `encoding='latin1'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the file in, without converting that file to a table, Pandas is the wrong tool. I'd suggest using `open()` from the standard library, and building the dataframe yourself.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        text = f.read()
    li.append({
        'filename': filename,
        'text': text,
    })
df = pd.DataFrame(li)
```

Comment: amazing! thanks a lot. a combination of this and Corralien's code encoding='latin1' worked :)